# Section Index Listview Adapter Item button can't click

Tags: android, android-listview

Anyone suggest me, why, I can't click Section Index Listview Adapter Item button? I can trigger `onitemclick`, but I can't create click event to inner adapter item button in section list view.

Comment: Please include some code.

Comment: I refered this link http://ngo-hung.com/blog/2012/11/18/ios-contact-listview-for-android. working fine.. In my senario i added social media icon in inner list item.. Now i cant click icon...

Comment: Please include relevant code so anyone looking to answer your question does not have to dig through your whole repo.